# jQuery code in if statement not running even though alert in if statement happens

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an if statement and there are two alerts inside it as well as a variable assignment. All three of these things happen when the condition is met.

But when I add jQuery code to the if statement's suite, that jQuery code doesn't happen.

**How can I get** `$('#tabViewWindow').animate({left:'100%'});` **to occur inside my condition?**

**The condition that I am trying to make the above code happen in is:**
`else if(obj.dx>0 && obj.$el.offset().left>=$(window).width()*0.6){`

Here is all my code:

```
$('#tabViewWindow').pep({
    axis: 'x',
    useCSSTranslation: false,
    drag: function (ev, obj) {
        if (obj.dx < 0 && obj.$el.offset().left > $(window).width() * 0.8) {
            //block left-drag when drag is left and object is 80% off screen
            obj.velocityQueue = new Array(5);
            return false;
        } else if (obj.dx > 0 && obj.$el.offset().left >= $(window).width() * 0.6) {
            //drag direction is right and object is 60% off screen
            alert("slide right here");
            open = false;
            alert("open is: " + open);
        } else if (obj.dx > 0) {
            open = true;
        }
        handleOpacity(ev, obj)
    },
});

function handleOpacity(ev, obj) {
    var opacity = 1 - (parseInt(obj.$el.css('left')) / $(window).width());
    obj.$el.css('opacity', opacity);
}
```

Comment: maybe #tabViewWindow element doesn't have position absolute or relative

Comment: What are the styles on #tabViewWindow? If you haven't set its position property then setting the left property won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `position:absolute;` or `position:relative;` (and at least initial `left` and `top` properties) to styles of `#tabViewWindow`. `left` property only applies to elements with that properties. Or if you want to leave position of element static you can animate `margin-left` property:

```
$('#tabViewWindow').animate({'margin-left' : '100%'}, 500);
```

Comment: does console say something?

Comment: Nope. Error free. For once, that is a bad thing.